# How (or where) can I ask something in order to understand a specific part of a specific book?

Tags: discussion

I'm reading a book (Varadarajan's  "Geometry of Quantum Theory") and I don't understand what it says about the universal covering group of the Galilean group. I'm afraid that the policy of math SE allows only setting a question about the universal covering group of the Galilean group, not about Varadarajan's sentences and notations, however, I need just this. Is there a regular way or a place (either on SE or other places) to ask such a question?

Answer (score 26):

It seems like it would be in scope here. You may want to include [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) or [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tags, if appropriate. Make sure that you quote the text verbatim, and try to get as specific as possible about what parts you don't understand.